# Assert fail - React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

i'm really new to react native and i encountered this error: 
`Components\MovieFocusCard.tsx: Assert fail`
`Failed building JavaScript bundle.`
when trying to run the app.

i already tried removing & reinstalling node_modules but it didn't help.

i have no clue why this error is showing up and what the error message itself means. So any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

this is the error that shows up on the phone:

[image: App Error]
package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.5",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.65",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Below the code from the MovieFocusCard component:

```
import MovieDetails from "../Types/MovieDetails";
import { NavigationInjectedProps, withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, Image } from "react-native";

type MovieFocusCardProps = {};
type MovieFocusCardState = {
  movieDetails: MovieDetails;
  loaded: boolean;
};

class MovieFocusCard extends Component<
  MovieFocusCardProps & NavigationInjectedProps,
  MovieFocusCardState
> {
  constructor(props: MovieFocusCardProps & NavigationInjectedProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movieDetails: null,
      loaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetMovieDetails(this.props.navigation.getParam("movieId", 0));
  }

  GetMovieDetails(id: number) {
    let url: string = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
    let apiKey: string = "?api_key=396734bc8915c8d1569cb4ff49b59c56";
    fetch(url + id + apiKey)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          movieDetails: data,
          loaded: true
        })
      )
      .catch(console.log);
  }

  render() {
    let posterUrl: string =
      "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200" + this.state.movieDetails.poster_path;

    let rdate = new Date(
      this.state.movieDetails.release_date
    ).toLocaleDateString();

    let element;
    this.state.loaded
      ? (element = (
          <View>
            <Text>{this.state.movieDetails.title}</Text>
            <Image source={{ uri: posterUrl }} />
            <Text>Release date: {rdate}</Text>
            <Text>Summary: {this.state.movieDetails.overview}</Text>
            <Text>Duration: {this.state.movieDetails.runtime} min</Text>
            <Button
              title="back"
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.goBack();
              }}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
          </View>
        ))
      : (element = <Text>Loading</Text>);
    return { element };
  }
}

export default withNavigation(MovieFocusCard);
//export default MovieFocusCard;
```

app.tsx code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import MovieFocusCard from "./Components/MovieFocusCard";
import MovieHome from "./Components/MovieHome";
import HomeScreen from "./Components/HomeScreen";

const MovieHomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Movies: { screen: MovieHome },
  MovieFocusCard: { screen: MovieFocusCard, params: { movieId: Number } }
});

const SerieHomeStack = createStackNavigator({});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({});

const MenuBarBottom = createAppContainer(
  createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Movies: {
        screen: MovieHomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Ionicons name="md-videocam" size={26} color={tintColor} />
          )
        }
      },
      Series: {
        screen: SerieHomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Ionicons name="md-tv" size={26} color={tintColor} />
          )
        }
      },
      Home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Ionicons name="md-heart" size={26} color={tintColor} />
          )
        }
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Home",
      activeColor: "#000000",
      inactiveColor: "#9e9e9e",
      barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#ffffff" },
      shifting: false //only shows label when clicked
    }
  )
);

export default MenuBarBottom;
```

Comment: So I'd try to restart everything by which I mean: stop the metro bundler, close all terminal and editors and reopen them. To be sure you could also restart your computer. Also, have you made any updates to your packages recently?

Comment: Have you moved any files? Especially the entry file?

Comment: restarting everything doesn't change anything. i also haven't moved any files but i have updated the packages a few days ago

Comment: Did it stop working then or is it unrelated?

Comment: I first added a bottomTabNavigator which worked fine. i then tried adding a stacknavigator inside each tab as shown on their site and then i started getting the error.

Comment: Are you using git? Can you revert until it works again? and then compare?

Comment: no it was meant to be an exercise but i should have done it.

Comment: My advice: If it's not too much code: start a new project and copy it over. Otherwise, maybe try: `cd android && ./gradlw clean` in your project root? (Oh this is on linux/unix, no idea on windows sorry)

Comment: i found out that the problem lies within the way i implement the stacknavigator inside the bottomtabnavigator so i'm gonna look further into that and see what needs to be changed. thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah well glad you found the error